# Android Market says my app is "not in targeted group" or "cannot be installed on this device"

Tags: android, sms, android-manifest, google-play

Been banging my head over this since yesterday morning. The direct webpage shows up but my app doesn't appear in search. On my 2.1 phone the app's page says "This item cannot be installed on this device." My friends with 2.2/2.3 phones get "You're not in the targeted group for this item."

Free app
Copy protection: Off
Content rating: Everyone
Supported devices: All Countries
Market developer product details shows:

> Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
>   Required device features
>   android.hardware.telephony
>   android.hardware.touchscreen
>   This application is available to over 720 devices.

More info below

The ironic thing here is I could use some karma right now X\ :)

Thanks,
Thien

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rainpattern.karma"
  android:versionCode="3"
  android:versionName="1.0.1">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
  <!-- Wondering if not specifying made BOTH required? -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.cdma" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

  <!-- Using Roboguice so my application to load modules in sub-pkg -->
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".sms.InstantKarma">

    <activity android:name=".ShowDeities" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**aapt d badging**

```
package: name='com.rainpattern.karma' versionCode='4' versionName='1.0.1'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.SEND_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'7'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.telephony.cdma'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.telephony.gsm'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
application-label:'Instant Karma'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='Instant Karma' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.rainpattern.karma.ShowDeities'  label='Instant Karma' icon=''
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
```

Comment: How come versionCode differs in your outputs? Also, on Market, it shows version 1.1 is available. So is it update you're having problems with or the one uploaded on 26th Dec?

Comment: I have exactly same problem. How did you fix the problem? Because now it is possible to download your app from market

Comment: Banging my head against this also.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem today where an initially published app would not show as compatible for any devices - the market website said "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."  And on the phone if you managed to open the app in the market it said "You're not in the targeted group for this item".  However, the developer console said it should be available on 943 devices.

I opened a ticket with Android support team ( https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=publishing ) and after a little back in forth with their automated systems, we got a response saying that they made some changes that may have resolved the problem.  I'm not sure if these were changes specific to our account, or if any account could have gotten the same error.
Before getting the email (while diligently troubleshooting), I had noticed that un-publishing and re-publishing the apk fixed the problem.

Conclusion: If anyone sees the problem where the developer console says the app is available on devices that the market is not allowing to install, try un-publishing and re-publishing your app (2 button clicks in the developer console) and if that doesn't work, open a ticket with google.