# App crashed when installed from Market but not if the Apk is installed manually.

Tags: android, google-play

My App works fine if I just install it manually by moving the apk onto the phone and installing it, however when I put it on the Market it crashes on the first Activity, this is the logcat.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  999): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mbwasi.funapp/com.mbwasi.funapp.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mbwasi.funapp.Splash in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mbwasi.funapp-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mbwasi.funapp.Splash in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mbwasi.funapp-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
E/AndroidRuntime(  999):        ... 11 more
```

What could be happening here? I also notice in the log that the apk name has a -1 at the end too,

```
com.mbwasi.funapp-1.apk
```

where would this be coming from?

Comment: do you obfuscate your code or run any tools to remove dead code?

Comment: @mbwasi Sounds like you might do without realising it. Check your ant.properties or build.properties file

Comment: Unless Android does obfuscation by default I am not doing it, I also don't have any of those files in my project. Anyway it works now, I'm chalking it up as a market problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I left it overnight, refreshed the market page for my App and now it not only shows as compatible with all my devices but also works when installed. So it was a Market issue. There was a tip in the other thread to unpublish and publish and I did that, no idea if it actually did anything though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on the same phone? Are you sure you are uploading the exact same APK? `ClassNotFoundException` could mean that some class your Splash activity is using is not found, you might be missing some library.

Comment: Same apk, I have now tried cleaning/repackaging and uploaded an update and now it is telling me its not compatible with any of my devices, it might be a problem with the Market like this guy was having http://stackoverflow.com/q/8645460/329034 gonna give it a few hours.